# Is there a way to generate a data-driven Monte Carlo sample from a histogram?

Tags: random, histograms, random-process, sampling

I have a vector with 50 elements. These are values of a random variable. I have represented the data as `Histogram[RandomVariable1Histogram]`. However, I need to obtain a bigger sample from said histogram, about 1000 values. If I were working with a known distribution, lets say a Gamma, I could simply write

```
nsim = 1000;
newValues = 
 RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[\[Alpha]0, \[Beta]0], nsim];
```

However, since I am currently dealing with an unknown random variable, I don't know how to sample said histogram. My only idea is to use [HistogramDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramDistribution.html) and somehow put the output inside of [RandomVariate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html). However, I am not very happy with this since it requires the calculation of a probability density function. Is there a better way of obtaining a sample of a random variable of which only a histogram is available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do this using "SmoothKernelDistribution".

Here is a simple example. We first create some data from a Normal Distribution:

```
d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
```

Then we get a smooth distribution from this data:

```
dist= SmoothKernelDistribution[d];
```

We can now test the outcome by sampling from this distribution and see if it is approximately normal:

```
rv = RandomVariate[dist, 1000];
Mean[rv]
Variance[rv]
Histogram[rv]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the documentation of SmoothKernelDistribution and attempted `empiricPDF = SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomVariable1Histogram]` and `d = RandomVariate[empiricPDF, 1000];` it seems to work if I write `Histogram[d]`

Comment: The answer needs to be modified. What is dist above?

Comment: This is exactly what one would do if the raw data is available.  But I read that the OP only has the histogram (bins and bin counts).

Comment: From a histogram one can always create some data with multiple entries.

Comment: @Asim. Thanks, it looks like I copied the wrong line. I corrected it.

Comment: Can you explain what "create some data with multiple entries" means?  Such a process might be randomly  choosing a bin (proportional to the count) and then either using the midpoint of the bin as the resulting value or taking a uniformly distributed random value within the bin.

Comment: You  can make it simple or complicated. The simplest is to take as many data point as the bin count indicates, all with the mean value of the bin. But of course you can guess a bin- variance but I do not see the value of it.

Answer (score 5):

This is precisely what [`RandomChoice`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html) does: choosing numbers according to weights. For example, if your histogram is

```
hist = {99, 217, 1026, 3};
```

then you can draw a random number from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that is distributed similarly with

```
RandomChoice[hist -> Range[Length[hist]]]
```

or you can draw $10^6$ numbers simultaneously with

```
RandomChoice[hist -> Range[Length[hist]], 10^6]
```